# Loot Generator, same variables

Tags: c#, var, repeat

So I made a random loot generator, the HP damage and mana are different but for some reason it only cycles between 2 item types for intance
rare mace, uncommon mace, rare boots, uncommon boots, legendary mace.
Even if I tell it to generate 20 items it sill only has 2 types.

This is the Generator

```
namespace TestingRNG
{
public class Items
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public int Defense { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int HP { get; set; }
    public int MANA { get; set; }
    public string Rarity { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfNames { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public Random Random = new Random();
    public List<string> ItemTypeList = new List<string> {"Weapon", "Armor" };
    public List<string> WeaponList = new List<string> { "Staff", "Sword", "Dagger", "Wand", "Axe", "Mace" };
    public List<string> ArmorList = new List<string> { "Chest area armor", "Shield", "Head area armor", "Leggings", "Shoes", "Gloves", "Belt", "Ring" };
    public string WeaponType { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<string> DamageType = new List<string> { "Meele", "Magic" };
    public List<string> WeaponListMeele = new List<string> { "Staff", "Wand" };
    public List<string> WeaponListMagic = new List<string> { "Sword", "Dagger", "Axe", "Mace" };
    public List<string> ValuePoor = new List<string> { "Wooden", "Bronze" };
    public List<string> ValueCommon = new List<string> { "Bronze", "Iron" };
    public List<string> Value2 = new List<string> { "Silver", "Steel", "Iron" };
    public List<string> ValueElite = new List<string> { "Silver", "Steel", "Dragon Glass", "Adamantium", "Titanium", "Arcane" };
    public List<string> ValueLegendary = new List<string> { "Dragon Glass", "Adamantium", "Titanium", "Arcane" };
    public List<string> ArmorValuePoor = new List<string> { "Cloth", "Leather" };
    public List<string> ArmorValueCommon = new List<string> { "Cloth", "Leather", "Iron" };
    public List<string> ArmorValue2 = new List<string> { "Iron", "Silver", "Steel" };
    public List<string> ArmorValueElite = new List<string> { "Silver", "Steel", "Titanium", "Arcane", "Dragon Glass", "Titanium" };
    public List<string> ArmorValueLegendary = new List<string> { "Titanium", "Arcane", "Dragon Glass", "Adamantium" };
    public List<string> Name1 = new List<string> { "Stupid", "Great", "Powerful", "Epic", "Masterfull", "Mighty", "Bountiful", "Foreverlasting", "Pointless", "Useless" };
    public List<string> Name2 = new List<string> { "Things", "Power", "Proportions", "Torment", "Legs", "Turnament", "Shit", "Crazyness", "Awesomeness" };
    public List<string> NameLenght3List = new List<string> { "Ragnarok", "Power", "Bondage", "Noobs", "Great Weakness", "Error", "404", "Torture", "SHIT STATS(No idea since I'm not good enough to programm stats based on names)", "The Dark Lord", "Emperor", "Monkey Kong", "I ran out of words", "Blablabla" };

    public Items(int iD,int droprarity)
    {
        ID = iD;
        int dropRarity = droprarity;
        NumberOfNames = NumberOfNamesGenerator(dropRarity);
        Rarity = RarityGenerator(dropRarity);
        ItemType = ItemTypeGenerator();
        if (ItemType == "Weapon")
        {
            WeaponType = DamageType[Random.Next(0, DamageType.Count)];

            if (ItemType == "Meele")
            {
                ItemType = WeaponListMeele[Random.Next(0, WeaponListMeele.Count)];
            }
            else
            {
                ItemType = WeaponListMagic[Random.Next(0, WeaponListMagic.Count)];
            }
        }
        if (ItemType == "Armor")
        {
            ItemType = ArmorList[Random.Next(0, ArmorList.Count)];
        }
        if (WeaponList.Contains(ItemType))
        {
            Value = WeaponValueGenerator(dropRarity);
            Damage = WeaponDamage(dropRarity);
        }
        else
        {
            Value = ArmorValueGenerator(dropRarity);
            HP = ArmorHealthGen(dropRarity);
            int RandomChance = Random.Next(0, 100);
            if (RandomChance <= 75)
            {
                MANA = ArmorManaGen(dropRarity);
            }
        }
        Name = NameGenerator();


    }
    public string RarityGenerator(int dropRarity)
    {
        switch (dropRarity)
        {
            case 1:
                Rarity = "Poor";
                break;
            case 2:
                Rarity = "Common";
                break;
            case 3:
                Rarity = "Uncommon";
                break;
            case 4:
                Rarity = "Elite";
                break;
            case 5:
                Rarity = "Rare";
                break;
            case 6:
                Rarity = "Legendary";
                break;
        }

        return Rarity;
    }
    public string ItemTypeGenerator()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}", ItemTypeList[Random.Next(0, ItemTypeList.Count)]);
    }
    public int NumberOfNamesGenerator(int dropRarity)
    {
        switch (dropRarity)
        {
            case 1:
                NumberOfNames = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 4);
                break;
            case 3:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 4);
                break;
            case 4:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 5);
                break;
            case 5:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 5);
                break;
            case 6:
                NumberOfNames = Random.Next(2, 6);
                break;
        }
        return NumberOfNames;
    }
    public string NameGenerator()
    {
        int nameNR = NumberOfNames;
        if (nameNR == 2)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Rarity, Value, ItemType);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 3)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} of {3}", Rarity, Value, ItemType, NameLenght3List[Random.Next(0, NameLenght3List.Count)]);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 4)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} of {3} {4}", Rarity, Value, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 5)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} of {3} {4} {5}", Rarity, Value, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
        }
        else if (nameNR == 6)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} of {3} {4} {5} {6}", Rarity, Value, ItemType, Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name1[Random.Next(0, Name1.Count)], Name2[Random.Next(0, Name2.Count)]);
        }
        else
        {
            string ErrorSword = "Error Sword/Armor/blablabla";
            return ErrorSword;
        }
    }
    public string WeaponValueGenerator(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                Value = ValuePoor[Random.Next(0, ValuePoor.Count)];
                break;
            case 2:
                Value = ValueCommon[Random.Next(0, ValueCommon.Count)];
                break;
            case 3:
                Value = Value2[Random.Next(0, Value2.Count)];
                break;
            case 4:
                Value = ValueElite[Random.Next(0, ValueElite.Count)];
                break;
            case 5:
                Value = ValueElite[Random.Next(0, ValueElite.Count)];
                break;
            case 6:
                Value = ValueLegendary[Random.Next(0, ValueLegendary.Count)];
                break;

        }
        return Value;
    }

    public string ArmorValueGenerator(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                Value = ArmorValuePoor[Random.Next(0, ArmorValuePoor.Count)];
                break;
            case 2:
                Value = ArmorValueCommon[Random.Next(0, ArmorValueCommon.Count)];
                break;
            case 3:
                Value = ArmorValue2[Random.Next(0, ArmorValue2.Count)];
                break;
            case 4:
                Value = ArmorValueElite[Random.Next(0, ArmorValueElite.Count)];
                break;
            case 5:
                Value = ArmorValueElite[Random.Next(0, ArmorValueElite.Count)];
                break;
            case 6:
                Value = ArmorValueLegendary[Random.Next(0, ArmorValueLegendary.Count)];
                break;

        }
        return Value;
    }

    public int WeaponDamage(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                Damage = Random.Next(5, 20);
                break;
            case 2:
                Damage = Random.Next(25, 45);
                break;
            case 3:
                Damage = Random.Next(50, 105);
                break;
            case 4:
                Damage = Random.Next(110, 200);
                break;
            case 5:
                Damage = Random.Next(210, 500);
                break;
            case 6:
                Damage = Random.Next(550, 1200);
                break;
        }
        return Damage;
    }

    public int ArmorHealthGen(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                HP = Random.Next(5, 20);
                break;
            case 2:
                HP = Random.Next(25, 45);
                break;
            case 3:
                HP = Random.Next(50, 105);
                break;
            case 4:
                HP = Random.Next(110, 200);
                break;
            case 5:
                HP = Random.Next(210, 500);
                break;
            case 6:
                HP = Random.Next(550, 1200);
                break;
        }
        return HP;
    }

    public int ArmorManaGen(int droprarity)
    {
        switch (droprarity)
        {
            case 1:
                MANA = Random.Next(5, 20);
                break;
            case 2:
                MANA = Random.Next(25, 45);
                break;
            case 3:
                MANA = Random.Next(50, 105);
                break;
            case 4:
                MANA = Random.Next(110, 200);
                break;
            case 5:
                MANA = Random.Next(210, 500);
                break;
            case 6:
                MANA = Random.Next(550, 1200);
                break;
        }
        return MANA;
    }
}
}
```

This is the part of the code that calls the generator and stores  them in a list, after that states its values.

```
namespace TestingRNG
{
class Program
{
    public Random Random = new Random();
    public int dropRate, itemAmmount;
    public List<Items> Loot = new List<Items>();
    public List<string> WeaponList = new List<string> { "Staff", "Sword", "Dagger", "Wand", "Axe", "Mace" };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program Program = new Program();
    }
    public Program()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many items do you want to generate");
        itemAmmount = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < itemAmmount; i++)
        {
            dropRate = Random.Next(1, 6);
            Loot.Add(new Items(i,dropRate));
        }
        foreach (var Item in Loot)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Item.Name);
            if (WeaponList.Contains(Item.ItemType))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Damage :{0}", Item.Damage);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HP :{0}",Item.HP);
                Console.WriteLine("MANA :{0}",Item.MANA);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When you say it always creates the same items... do you mean the first time you run it? or every single time you run it? Random isn't really all that random.... (Stick a second call to the program call in your main method to see what happens)

Comment: `public Random Random = new Random();` -- you're creating a new `Random` object for every `Items` in a tight loop. Don't do that! Usually you have *one* static `Random` object for your whole application (or at least only one per thread). -- So try changing that to `public static Random Random = new Random();` and see if that helps.

Comment: to add to what @Sayse said,  when you create a `Random()` object it initialises and runs an algorithem based on the current timestamp rounded to seconds,   so if your code runs and completes all 20 iterations within that 1 second it will create the same seed every time,   add `Thread.Sleep(1500)` in your for loop that creates the new items and run that,  you should see your random values start occuring.

Comment: @Nikerym - Not quite what I said, and adding thread.sleep won't help anything, you will just be adding a different *set* of "random" numbers and make the program slower. There is lots of material available about making random more random, depends how much the op needs

Comment: @sayse yes it will make the program slower,  but it will demonstrate where his issue is.  it's that he's generating `itemAmount` of `Random()` objects all with the same seed (because default is based on a timestamp) increasing the wait period between the creation of the `Random()` objects will demonstrate the issue.  How to resolve it is to do as you say and create a global random which is then passed through.

Comment: No it creates new items each time but only 2 types of new items, for some reason it gives some variables different values but keeps other variables same.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this comes from using two different instances of Random, one in your Items class and one in your main program. To fix this, I changed your items class to accept the main program's random as a parameter and everything worked perfectly.

**Items.cs**

**...**

```
        public string ItemType { get; set; }
        public Random Random;
        public List<string> ItemTypeList = new List<string> { "Weapon", "Armor" };
```

**...**

```
        public Items(int iD, int droprarity, Random random)
        {
            Random = random;
            ID = iD;
```

**Program.cs**

...

```
            dropRate = Random.Next(1, 6);
            Loot.Add(new Items(i, dropRate, Random));
```

**EDIT:**
To expand on  Nikerym's comment, when a new Random is created it is based on the current time; as all your items were being generated at the same time, each using a new Random, this lead to the same number being generated each time.

The use of Random.Next() was correct, it just needed to be the same Random as used in the above class!

Comment: the issue is that he is executing code with the Random's running off the same seed (his code is small so executes in under a few milliseconds,  but since the random default seed is based on timestamp he is getting the same values)

you can use multiple random variables,  they just have to be initialized at least 1 second apart.

Comment: Well, not only *two* different instances of `Random`, but actually `itemAmmount + 1` different instances of `Random` created in close succession and thus very likely to have the same seed (`Environment.TickCount`). But your solution to pass the `Random` object is perfect for this situation.

Comment: If possible could you please mark this as the accepted answer if this worked for you! Glad I could help.